# How to get id or pass id to datatables from serverside in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

I am working on `datatables` server-side Processing in **codeigniter**. Everything is working fine, but I want to pass the `id` from the controller inside some columns.

I've tried this code, but the `id` is not being received:

**MyController**

```php
foreach($fetch_data as $row) {
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $no++;
    $sub_array[] = "<td id='$row->id'>$row->program</td>";
    $sub_array[] = $row->semester;
    $sub_array[] = $row->name;
}
```

After this the table column look like this.`<td>Program</td>`

[image]

How to receive the `id` in the `<td id="1">Program</td>` form?

Comment: Why you pass id from where? whats you need this?

Comment: You shouldn't be generating any html markup from within your Controller -- that is what the View layer is for.  We don't have enough information to provide a professional answer.

Answer (score 2):

update with

```
$sub_array[] = "<td id=".$row->id.">".$row->program."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

`$sub_array[] = "<td id='$row->id'>$row->program</td>";`

In the above code, you have wrapped `$row->id` in the single quote(') which causes a problem.
Update your code with

`$sub_array[] = "<td id='".$row->id."'>".$row->program."</td>";`

Comment: i use `datatables from server processing`

Comment: I need id or some other attributes because I want when I click on specific coloum it convert into text field then I will update that data with the help of Ajax.

Comment: Did you have better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **onclick function** for this task. When you click on the specific td the value get in function and perform ajax.

```
$sub_array[] = "<td onclick='your_function(".$row->id.")'>".$row->program."</td>";
```

Than in jquery call the function

```
function your_function(id='')
{
  if(id!='')
  {
    //your ajax call here
  }
}
```